# Changing a segment value in a string

Tags: javascript, string

I need your help,

How can I replace the segment 52XX (value after the 2nd dash) in the following string?

Ie.

```
var str = '4-D-52XX-P4X-12X-08XX-XXX-0000-9'

var x = '5300'

str  = '4-D-5300-P4X-12X-08XX-XXX-0000-9'
```

I scoured the web, but couldn't find the help I was so desperately looking for.

Comment: With a regular expression replacement? You didn't search a lot...

Comment: Google "javascript replace" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var str = '4-D-52XX-P4X-12X-08XX-XXX-0000-9'
var query = "52XX"
var replacement = '5300'

var newStr = str.replace(query, replacement);
console.log(newStr)
```

```html
<a href="
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace">Docs</a>
```